# PHP Regex Remove leading and trailing <br /> within <p> tags

Tags: php, regex

I can't figure this out for the life of me.

I need a regex expression that will strip out any leading or trailing `<br>` tags within `<p>` tags.

For example.

`<p>
  <br />Some test text. <br /> Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. <br /><br /><br />
</p>`

Should become...

`<p>Some test text. <br /> Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text.</p>`

I feel as though this should be very simple but I've hit a road-block. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start your search again but with HTML processing with DOMDocument, you'll find some good solutions that don't require hard to maintain regular expressions.

Comment: For a really fool-proof solution, you shouldn't try to use regex for this. If this will be used with an isolated set of strings, regex would work, but an HTML parser will be much simpler when you start looking at corner cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a look-ahead and look-behind for `<p>` and `</p>`, and a non-capturing group for 1 or more occurrences of some variation of `<br>`.

For matching leading `<br/>` tags:

```
(?<=<p>)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>)+\s*
```

For matching trailing `<br/>` tags:

```
(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>)+\s*(?=<\/p>)
```

Both together:

```
(?<=<p>)(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>)+\s*|(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>)+\s*(?=<\/p>)
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cT3dM5/1)

Comment: Works great! Thanks heaps.

Comment: @TomeA Awesome! Be sure you actually understand how it works though. I didn't mean to just hand you some code to copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this without regular expressions.

```
// Method1 :: Finding and replacing unwanted tags
$str1 = '<p> <br />Some test text. <br /> Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. <br /><br /><br /></p>';

$findTags = array('<br>', '<br />');
$replacement = array();

// Case insensitive replacement
$str1 = str_ireplace($findTags, $replacement, $str1);
print_r($str1);

// Method 2:: Stripping all HTML tags except allowed tags

$str2 = '<p> <br />Some test text. <br /> Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. <br /><br /><br /></p>';
$str2 = strip_tags($str2, '<p>');

echo $str2;
?>
```

Reference Links:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php